# How to transform this into a dataframe and save it as a csv?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-wrangling

[image: 1]

This data was earlier provided as a `.txt` file. I converted it to `.csv` format and tried to sort it into the wanted form, but failed. I am trying to find ways to convert this data structure (as displayed below):

```
bakeryA
77300 Baker Street
bun: [10,20,30,10]
donut: [20,10,40,0]
bread: [0,10,15,10]
bakery B
78100 Cerabut St
data not available
bakery C
80300 Sulkeh St
bun: [29,50,20,30]
donut: [10,10,30,10]
bread: [10,15,10,20]
```

into this data frame:

| Name | Address | type | salt | sugar | water | flour |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bakery A | 77300 Baker Street | bun | 10 | 20 | 30 | 10 |
| Bakery A | 77300 Baker Street | donut | 20 | 10 | 40 | 0 |
| Bakery A | 77300 Baker Street | bread | 0 | 10 | 15 | 10 |
| Bakery B | 78100 Cerabut St | Nan | Nan | Nan | Nan | Nan |
| Bakery C | 80300 Sulkeh St | bun | 29 | 50 | 20 | 30 |
| Bakery C | 80300 Sulkeh St | donut | 10 | 10 | 30 | 10 |
| Bakery C | 80300 Sulkeh St | bread | 10 | 15 | 10 | 20 |

Thank you!

Comment: The data you have given is not CSV as the values are not separated by commas...

Comment: @prnvbn, Sorry! the file was opened in Excel, but saved as .csv. I have re-edited my question. Thank you for the comment!

Comment: Can you elaborate on this data structure a bit more? What file format is this?

Comment: @DerekO, I have updated my post with a screenshot of the data. The data was earlier provided as a txt file. I converted it to a csv format and tried to sort it into the wanted form, but failed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This has very little to do with pandas and more with parsing non-structured source into structured data. Try this:

```py
from ast import literal_eval
from enum import IntEnum

class LineType(IntEnum):
    BakeryName = 1
    Address = 2
    Ingredients = 3

data = []
with open('data.txt') as fp:
    line_type = LineType.BakeryName
    for line in fp:
        line = line.strip()

        if line_type == LineType.BakeryName:
            name = line # the current line contains the Bakery Name
            line_type = LineType.Address # the next line is the Bakery Address
        elif line_type == LineType.Address:
            address = line # the current line contains the Bakery Address
            line_type = LineType.Ingredients # the next line contains the Ingredients
        elif line_type == LineType.Ingredients and line == 'data not available':
            data.append({
                'Name': name,
                'Address': address
            }) # no Ingredients info available
            line_type = LineType.BakeryName # next line is Bakery Name
        elif line_type == LineType.Ingredients:
            # if the line does not follow the ingredient's format, we
            # overstepped into the Bakery Name line. Then the next line
            # is Bakery Address
            try:
                bakery_type, ingredients = line.split(':')
                ingredients = literal_eval(ingredients.strip())
                data.append({
                    'Name': name,
                    'Address': address,
                    'type': bakery_type,
                    'salt': ingredients[0],
                    'sugar': ingredients[1],
                    'water': ingredients[2],
                    'flour': ingredients[3],
                })
            except:
                name = line
                line_type = LineType.Address

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

This assume that your data file is in the format shown. A slight deviation (blank lines, for example) will throw it off.